# Using if statements in jQuery for prompt box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently learning jQuery and have researched this question beforehand but cannot get the answer I need. Basically I am making a to do list. Before the form loads a user is **prompted** to enter their name and it will be appended to the class of . This works fine, but I'm trying to make the container hide() if the value entered in the input box === 0. Heres my code below and I would be grateful if someone could help me.

```
    var listName = prompt("What do you want to call your list?");

    if ( $(prompt).length === 0 ) {

        $('.container').hide();

    }
    else {

        $("h2").html(listName);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your prompt response value is stored inside your variable `listName` so you should use it.
Also you might want to toggle the view of your container *otherwise*:

```
var listName = prompt("What do you want to call your list?");

$('.container').toggle(!!listName); // Show .container is listName has value (is true)
$('h2').text( listName );
```

Also make sure you've placed your `<script>` tag right before the closing `</body>` tag or wrap your jQuery inside [document.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready)

Comment: Thank you. Could I ask, what do the '!!' mean in front of listName? Also I noticed no if or else statements were used. It works, but how?

Comment: @JackThomson the `!` is the Not operator and it's used to convert whatever is returned from `listName` to a `boolean` value (`true`/`false`). The `!!` just turns `boolean` to `!boolean` or in other words doubles the conversion. Prompt returns an empty string `""`, which if than set to boolean inside an `if` statement will return `false`, if your string has a value like `"Foo"` it will make it `true`, so `!!"Foo"` results as `true`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var listName = prompt("What do you want to call your list?");
        if ( listName === 0 ) {
            $('.container').hide();
        }
        else {
            $("h2").html(listName);
        }
});
```

Comment: Thank you but this doesn't hide the class container? The problem still persists